# wxPython subclass getting attributes from class

Tags: python, oop, wxpython

I have a wxpython program where I subclass wx.Dialog as per a tutorial.  Within the dialog I create a panel and a sizer.

```
class StretchDialog(wx.Dialog):

'''A generic image processing dialogue which handles data IO and user interface.
This is extended for individual stretches to allow for the necessary parameters
to be defined.'''

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(StretchDialog, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.InitUI()
    self.SetSize((600,700))

def InitUI(self):
    panel =  wx.Panel(self)
    sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(10,5)
```

The block comment describes what functionality I am trying to achieve, essentially dynamically generating more complex dialogs using this as the base.  To do that I have tried:

```
class LinearStretchSubClass(StretchDialog):
'''This class subclasses Stretch Dialog and extends it by adding 
    the necessary UI elements for a linear stretch'''

def InitUI(self):
    '''Inherits all of the UI items from StretchDialog.InitUI if called as a method'''
    testtext = wx.StaticText(panel, label="This is a test")
    sizer.Add(testtext, pos=(10,3))
```

I call the subclass via the InitUI method to be able to extend, but not overwrite the UI generation in the parent class' InitUI.  What I am not able to do is pass the panel and presumably sizer attributes from the parent to the child.

I tried many variations of panel = StretchDialog.panel and panel = StretchDialog.InitUI.panel to no end.

Is it possible to achieve this in wxpython by subclassing a parent?  If so, how am I messing up the namespace when trying to access panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your InitUI in the child class causes InitUI not to be called in StretchDialog

you can do it like this

```
class StretchDialog(wx.Dialog):

    '''A generic image processing dialogue which handles data IO and user interface.
      This is extended for individual stretches to allow for the necessary parameters
      to be defined.'''

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(StretchDialog, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.InitUI()
        self.SetSize((600,700))

   def InitUI(self):
       #save references for later access
       self.panel =  wx.Panel(self)
       self.sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(10,5)
```

Then in your child class

```
class LinearStretchSubClass(StretchDialog):
'''This class subclasses Stretch Dialog and extends it by adding 
the necessary UI elements for a linear stretch'''

    def InitUI(self):
    '''Inherits all of the UI items from StretchDialog.InitUI if called as a method'''
         StretchDialog.InitUI(self) #call parent function
         testtext = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="This is a test")
         self.sizer.Add(testtext, pos=(10,3))
```

Comment: Wrks wonderfully.  I will have to go back and reread all of the namespace documentation to make sure that I fully grasp the passing of variables between a parent and a child.  Thanks!